# Is it possible to get the text of a script that is loaded from a source as opposed to in line code?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

**Currently I'm just taking source of a script that is on the page.**

The HTML:

```
<script type="text/plain">meow</script>
```

The JavaScript:

```
// returns "meow"
document.querySelector('script').text
```

**I want to be able to load the script from another file.**

The HTML:

```
<script type="text/plain" src="file.txt"></script>
```

file.txt:

```
meow
```

The JavaScript:

```
// returns "meow"
document.querySelector('script').textFromFile
```

**Does anyone know if that's possible? I would assume it's not, and I haven't found anything on google that is what I'm asking.**

Comment: Why are you not reading it with an XMLHttpRequest? There is no need to add it via a script tag.

Comment: I'm just messing around with a few things. I favor the script tag over XHR anyways :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `script` has a `src` attribute you would  need to fire of a request via XHR to that same path and pull in the text content of its response. Keep in mind this will require additional work if the script is being loaded from another domain. At that point you would need to make use of CORS, or introduce some other type of proxy to handle the cross-domain communication.

Comment: I can do that, but what about local or offline files?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about local files; are you talking about files loaded with the file:// protocol? Offline files should be handled by your manifest.